# array merge with multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. I want to merge them.

**array 1:**

```
Array
(
[100] => 
[50] => 
[CREDIT] => 14.31
[CHEQUE] => 
)
```

**array 2:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 501
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 502
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 503
    )
```

I am getting this result after merging them with `$array1+$array2`:

```
Array
(
[100] => 
[50] => 
[CREDIT] => 14.31
[CHEQUE] => 
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 501
    )
)
```

And my expected result is:

```
Array
(
[100] => 
[50] => 
[CREDIT] => 14.31
[CHEQUE] => 
[0] => Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 501
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 502
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 503
        )
    )
)
```

What could be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `array_merge($array1, $array2)` ?

Comment: There are numeric `KEYS` in my array. I can not use that function.

Comment: How about `$array1[0] = $array2`?

Comment: I can't say what the reason is, which was your question; but this will do what you want: `$array1 + array($array2)`

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case and as $Sadiq mentioned, I would simply do `$array1[0] = $array2`.

```
$arr1 = [
    '100' => '',
    '50' => '',
    'CREDIT' => 14.31,
    'CHEQUE' => ''
];

$arr2 = [
    '0' => [
        'id' => 501
    ],
    '1' => [
        'id' => 502
    ],
    '2' => [
        'id' => 503
    ],
];

$arr1[0] = $arr2;
print_r($arr1);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [100] => 
    [50] => 
    [CREDIT] => 14.31
    [CHEQUE] => 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 501
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 502
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 503
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1= array(100=>'',50=>'','CREDIT'=>14.31,'CHEQUE'=>'');
print_r($arr1);

$arr2  = array(0 => array('id' => 501),1 => array ( 'id' => 502),2 => array('id'=> 503));
print_r($arr2);

$result = $arr1 + array($arr2);
print_r($result);
```

**Result :**

```
Array
    (
        [100] => 
        [50] => 
        [CREDIT] => 14.31
        [CHEQUE] => 
    )

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 501
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 502
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 503
            )

    )

    Array
    (
        [100] => 
        [50] => 
        [CREDIT] => 14.31
        [CHEQUE] => 
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 501
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 502
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 503
                    )

            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

These will work with as many arrays as you need and with as many dimensions needed.

For these functions, set the highest priority array to the lowest index:

```
function overlapArrays($array) {
    if(count($array) > 1) {
        for($i = (count($array) - 1);$i >= 0;$i--) {
            if(($i - 1) >= 0) {
                prioritize($array[$i], $array[$i - 1]);
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return $array[0];
    }
    else {
        return $array;
    }
}

function prioritize($arr1, &$arr2) {
    foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $arr2)) {
            $arr2[$key] = $value;
        }
        elseif(is_array($value) && is_array($arr2[$key])) {
            prioritize($value, $arr2[$key]);
        }
    }
}

$array1 = [
    100 => '',
    50 => '',
    'CREDIT' => 14.31,
    'CHEQUE' => ''
];

$array2 = [
    0 => [
        'id' => 501
    ],
    1 => [
        'id' => 502
    ],
    2 => [
        'id' => 503
    ]
];

$merger = Array($array1, $array2);

$results = overlapArrays($merger);
```

For instance, if you want keys that exist both in the first array and second array to be preserved in the first array then you assign the first array to the 0 index in the merge array. If you want array2 to preserve values when there are matches, then assign array2 to the 0 index.

```
$array1 = Array(
    'one' => Array(
         'two' => 2,
         'three' => 3
    )
);
$array2 = Array(
    'one' => Array(
        'two' => 3,
    )
);
$merger = Array($array2, $array1);

$results = overlapArrays($merger);
```

results =

```
Array(
    'one' => Array(
        'two' => 3,
        'three' => 3
    )
);
```

The array with the highest index in the merger array has the lowest priority. The array with the lowest index in the merger array has the highest priority. Let me know if you have enough questions. I'm trying to make sure I explained it well enough.